# Ranking Text Posts based on NER Tags

Tags: natural-language, ranking, tf-idf, named-entity-recognition

I have a list of NER tags ranked by the number of times they appear in a database of articles, with the highest count listed first.

I am trying to figure out how to score the articles based on:

1. How many times the tags appear in them
2. The weight of the tag. The tag with the highest count in the tag list weighs more
3. The frequency of the tag in the article

Any thoughts on what a very simple algorithm might look like? I've explored some ideas around TF-IDF but they do not factor the weight of the tag itself.